# Windows Update Issue - Windows 10 v.1909 to 22H2 - Error code 0xc190010a

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

First time user here on ServerFault. I've utilized the forums a lot but this is my first time asking a question/engaging with the community.

I am a NetAdmin for my company and I've never encountered this issue and I wanted to reach out to the SF aerosphere.

Here's my issue. An employee that I'm working on their laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T470) hasn't had a Win update in over a year. I have physically seen failed updates since 2/8/22 and the OS is the only one that is failing. The OS is currently at version 1909 and I need to bring it up to current.

So far this has been my mode/process of elimination and I'm needing some direction/ideas.

```
Check for adequate storage space. 93.1GB of free storage.
Ran Windows Update Troubleshooter. No issues found.
Checked Lenovo Vantage for backed up updates. BIOS update was not updated for about a year. Didn't fix the issue.
I cleared Windows Update cache. Mostly. I cleared the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download folder. Then restarted the WinUpdate Service. Not change.
Performed a clean boot. No change.
Reset Windows Update Components. "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution" and "C:\Windows\System32\catroot2" and saved them into new folder SoftwareDistribution.old and catroot2.old.
```

I'm stuck and not sure what to do. My next idea is to go onto Microsoft's site and manually push the next version from 1909 to... 20H1..?

Anyways, thank you for your advice, answers, etc.

Comment: have you tried all the steps in [this page](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/0xc190010a.html) or [this one](https://www.howtoedge.com/solve-0xc190010a-or-0xc190010d/) - there's more if you search for that error - seems you've done some, but the one thing that stands out is 3rd party anti-virus

Comment: `My next idea is to go onto Microsoft's site and manually push the next version`.  What ever happened to downloading the ISO of the target Windows version you are supporting to the endpoint, mounting it, and running setup.exe?